# How can I stop iOS from asking to save an incorrect password?

Tags: ios

I'm rebuilding the login screen for our app, and getting some annoying behavior from iOS for failed logins. After the user enters a username and password, when I show a new view controller, the system pops up a sheet asking if I want to save the username and password.

This would just be okay if it only showed up for successful logins, but it also asks to save the password after the user fails to log in and taps the Cancel button to quit trying.

How does iOS determine when to show this sheet, and is there any way to tell it not to bother saving an incorrect password? Is this feature actually documented anywhere? I've seen the [Password AutoFill](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill) page, but there's really not much there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the username and password field contents to `nil` before dismissing the view controller, then iOS will not prompt to save the account information.